# PHP : Iterating through FTP folder and create an HTML table

Tags: php, html, ftp

I am new to PHP and for the sake of simplicity, I'll say that I am trying to create a crude website in which I want make an HTML table that checks the contents of an FTP folder and either adds a dot to the table if the target is found and an empty cell (w/ a &nbsp) if not.

Here is my code and the folder structure:

```
<table border=1 >
<?php
foreach ($demolist as &$value) {

    if($value != "." && $value != ".." && $value!=".DS_Store" ){
        ?> <tr> <?php
        echo '<td> <a href="./layouts/'.$value.'/index.html'.'">'.$value.'</a </td>';

        $png = $prezLayouts.$value;

        echo $png.'<br>';

        $sizeList = ftp_nlist($connection, $png);
        natsort($sizeList);

        foreach($sizeList as $target) {

            if($target != "." && 
               $target != ".." && 
               $target !=".DS_Store" && 
               $target != "index.html") {

                echo $target."<br>";

                if ($target == '640.png') { ?> <td> <?php echo "&#8226";  ?> </td> <?php  }

                elseif ($target == '768.png') { ?> <td> <?php echo "&#8226";  ?> </td> <?php }

                elseif ($target == '1000.png') { ?> <td> <?php echo "&#8226";  ?> </td> <?php }

                elseif ($target == '1200.png') { ?> <td> <?php echo "&#8226";  ?> </td> <?php }

                else { ?> <td> <?php echo "&nbsp"; ?> </td> <?php } ?>

                <?php 
            }

        }   
    ?> </tr> <?php
    }
}       
?> </table>
```

OUTPUT from loop echo's

```
/domains/~~/html/demo/layouts/about
1000.png
1200.png
/domains/~~/html/demo/layouts/buy
640.png
768.png
/domains/~~/html/demo/layouts/contact
640.png
768.png
1000.png
1200.png
/domains/~~/html/demo/layouts/homepage
640.png
1000.png
1200.png
/domains/~~/html/demo/layouts/social
640.png
```

Now, my problem is that getting the list of the files in each folder won't let me check for files that *don't exist* in the folder. (doi) The only crude solution I can think of is creating a static array with [640.png, 768.png, 1000.png, 1200.png] and use that to check against the files in the folders, but I'm positive there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Taking a stab that image file names are all a number and `.png`, correct? I see lots of ways to improve your code, but it's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Twisty ^Accidental comment^   
Yes, the only files that can be in the folder are [640.png,768.png,1000.png, 1200.png]
 
Take (/domains/~~/html/demo/layouts/social) which only contains the file 640.png. Right now, the table row for ./social only contains one cell with the &#8226 character, signifying the presence of 640.png. What I am trying to do, is  create three more (blank) cells to signify the lack of 768.png, 1000.png and 1200.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try the code below. It is a good practice to not break in and out of PHP and HTML if possible.

```
<?php
// Start HTML Table wrapper
$table = "<table border=1>\r\n";

foreach ($demolist as &$value) {
    if($value != "." && $value != ".." && $value != ".DS_Store"){
        // Start Table Row wrapper
        $table .= "<tr>\r\n";
        // First Cell
        $table .= "<td><a href='./layouts/$value/index.html'>$value</a></td>";
        $png = $prezLayouts.$value;
        // Second Cell
        table .= "<td>$png</td>";
        // This section does not make sense... your HTML table could result in uneven columns.
        $sizeList = ftp_nlist($connection, $png);
        natsort($sizeList);

        foreach($sizeList as $target) {
            // We have already ruled out 3 conditions above, so we only need to rule out index.html
            if($target != "index.html") {
                $table .= "<td>" . (strripos($target, ".png")?"&#8226;":"&nbsp;") . "</td>";
            }
        }   
    }
    // Close Table Row wrappper
    $table .= "</tr>\r\n";
}
// Close Table wrapper
$table .= "</table>\r\n";
echo $table;
?>
```

One improvement I can suggest, if you know the total number of PNG files or all the titles that could be, can use that. Either a `for()` loop or make an array of the possible file names.

```
$imageNames = array("640.png", "768.png", "1000.png", "1200.png");
$imageExists = array();
$sizeList = ftp_nlist($connection, $png);
natsort($sizeList);

foreach($imageNames as $n) {
    foreach($sizeList as $target){
        $imageExists[$n] = true;
    }
}
foreach($imageExists as $e){
    $table .= "<td>" . ($e)?"$#8226;":"&nbsp;" . "</td>";
}
```

Since we are looking for 4 specific file names, we iterate all possible values, looking for each file name. This will ensure that you have a value for each possible file name. And make your column count the same on each row.

**Maybe better:**

```
foreach($imageNames as $n) {
    $table .= "<td>" . (array_search($n, $sizeList)?"&#8226;":"&nbsp;") . "</td>"
}
```

Comment: its erroring on strripos(".png") in the foreach($sizeList as $target) loop, saying that it expects two parameters.

Comment: Too quick, fixed: `strripos($target, ".png")`

Comment: I see what you mean. The code you created a table with the right amount of rows, but the foreach($sizeList as $target) and the foreach() nested inside it created 15 blank cells for one target found :( As always, I appreciate your help

Comment: See new edits - took me a moment to figure out a logic that would do what you want. Looks for 4 specific file names, and ping if it is found.

Comment: ok so its outputting 20 &#8226 characters, when it should be 12 characters with 8 spaces. Also it's not entering them into the table at all. Ill continue to tinker because you are right about the logic of it